# How to configure PlatformIO for ESP32-SOLO-1?

Tags: esp32, platformio

I've a simple led blinking example which I'm trying to run on a ESP32-SOLO-1 but as soon I flash it with the program I get the following message from the serial monitor:

```
E (102) cpu_start: Running on single core chip, but application is built with dual core support.
E (102) cpu_start: Please enable CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE option in menuconfig.
abort() was called at PC 0x400829d2 on core 0
```

Here's the code

```c
#include <Arduino.h>
#define LED_BUILTIN 2

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

And the `platformio.ini` config:

```
[env:esp-wrover-kit]
platform = espressif32
board = esp-wrover-kit
monitor_speed = 115200
framework = arduino
build_flags = -D  CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE
```

Adding the build flag `CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE` has no effect.

Comment: According to the platformio forum the correct build flag should be
build_flags = -DCONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE=1

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Comment: At the moment, there is no feasible way. The Arduino framework uses pre-compiled libraries, which have been built without `-DCONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE=1`, and so would have to be rebuilt.